# Lambda function passing an argument Python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm new in python and I just see some code like this:

```
title = 'Thank'
def write():
    a = lambda x: title + ' ' +  x
    return a
who = write()
print(who('you'))
```

It'resulf returns to **'Thank you'** but my think about 'Write' function does not take an argument, so why dose we can pass an argument for 'who'?

Comment: This should not have been written as a lambda, which is just an anonymous function, that is immediately assigned to a variable ... so why? `def add_title(x): return title + ' ' +  x`. Now that we've got `lambda` out of the way, what you are looking at is a _closure_. That's what you want to study.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `write` does not take an argument, hence we call it without an argument:

```
who = write()
```

The *return value of `write`*, which is assigned to the variable `who`, is the object being referenced by the local variable `a`, which is the object that is the result of the expression `lambda x: title + " " + x`. This evaluates to a function object, just the same as `write`, however, this one *does* take a parameter, a single positional paramter `x`. We can call this with one parameter just so:

```
>>> title = 'Thank'
>>> (lambda x: title + ' ' +  x)('foo')
'Thank foo'
```

Note, `lambda x: title + ' ' + x` is being returned from `write`, so the above is equivalent to:

```
>>> def write():
...     a = lambda x: title + ' ' +  x
...     return a
...
>>> write()('foo')
'Thank foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a `lambda` inside your function, `lambda` is essentially a function, your code is equivalent to:

```
title = 'Thank'
def write():
    def a(x):
        return title + ' ' +  x
    return a
who = write()
print(who('you'))
```

The `write` doesn't take parameters, but the function/lambda inside does, which is `a`:

So calling `write()('you')` would mean to first get into the `write` function then using the parenthesis again would bring the code into the `a` lambda/function, which would require a parameter (which is `'you'` in this case).

Obviously this code also outputs:

```
Thank you
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following function, `a` is a function which returns `title + ' ' + x`.

When you do `return a`, you are returning the *function*.

```
def write():
    a = lambda x: title + ' ' +  x
    return a
who = write()
```

If you try to print `who`, you can see something like this:

```
<function write.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001CC1810C5E0>
```

This lambda function can also be written as the

```
def write():
    def a(x):
        return title+' '+x
    return a
```

Where you are returning the function. Since it takes a parameter called `x`, you pass it on to `who`.

So, you are returning a function which takes 1 argument. This is why you are passing something as a parameter to `who`.

When you define `write`, you don't provide any parameters in the definition: `def write()`. So you can simply call the function: `who=write()`

But, you define `a` as taking *1* argument because it is defined as `lambda x:`. If you don't want to pass an argument, you can set a default value for `x` like `lambda x="There":`. This way, if you don't pass a parameter, it will still not raise an error because it will take the default value of `x` which is `There`

Answer (score 1):

A lambda is an anonymous function and is used in places where there is no need to name the function. An example is a function that takes another function as a paramter

```
sorted(my_int_list, key=lambda i: i % 12)
```

Lambdas shouldn't just be assigned to variables, that defeats the purpose. Your code is better written as

```
title = 'Thank'
def write():
    def a(x):
        return title + ' ' +  x
    return a

who = write()
print(who('you'))
```

Now that we've gotten rid of the lambda red herring, its easy to see that `a` is an *inner function* to `write`. The next thing to consider is variable scope. Since neither `a` nor its outer function `write` assign a value to `title`, `title` is not local to either of them and will be looked up in the global scope.

`write` returns function `a`, which is just a normal callable function. `a` takes a single parameter and adds it to whatever is in the global `title` variable. You can call it as often as you want, and if `title` is changed, that change is reflected in the call. To demonstrate, run with the `-i` option and test

```
$ python3 -i test.py
Thank you
>>> print('type', who)
type <function write.<locals>.a at 0x7f2b3b409c10>
>>> title = "Something completely different"
>>> print(who('you'))
Something completely different you
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are passing the argument to return value of `write` function i.e. a `lambda`, not to the `write` function.

The below code tries to pass argument to `write` function, it will result in `TypeError: write() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

```
title = "Thank"

def write():
    a = lambda x : title + " " + x
    return a

who = write
print(who("You"))
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
title = "Thank"

who = lambda x : title + " " + x

print(who("You"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, the argument 'you' is not meant for the write() function but for the anonymous(lambda) function inside the write() function.